# Is there any way to calculate my accepted percentage?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, statistics

Is there any way on stack overflow to calculate my accepted percentage? By accepted, I mean the percent of questions I have answered that have been marked as the accepted answer. (eg 45/205 = 21.95%)

In fact, more generically - are there ways for me to calculate stats that aren't displayed for my account or other user's account on stack overflow?

Comment: You can probably get all the stats you want by querying the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "marked as ACCEPTED" not "correct answer".  there is a difference

Comment: @Plutonix I agree completely, which is why I put "correct" in quotes. I should have used the wording "accepted" instead!

Comment: @Stijn Excellent link! I used [get user id](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82664/get-user-id-from-display-name) followed by a [query to get the percent](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1969/number-of-answers-accepted-answers-and-accepted-percent) to get what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This would be nifty to see as a global ranking.